# openCL and crashing, is there a better way to find memory leaks? (JOCL)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, find, opencl

I have been auditing my calling code for openCL for a while and I cannot find any memory leaks. Note, I am using JOCL, so I have a bunch of JUnit tests. If I run any of my tests individually or if I run 4/5 of any of my tests it always passes, but it always fails if I run all my tests on one of my three boxes that has a weaker graphics card. I assume this has to be a memory leak problem. Is openCL just known to be leaky? Are there better ways of finding memory leaks than just tracing through my code in the debugger?

I get this error on my weaker box. I can also get it on my stronger boxes if I increase the memory usage on my JUnit tests, which is expected if I make it high enough. When this happens on my weaker box, it will fail randomly on puny < 1MB of GPU memory tests if a all the other tests were run before it. I am using Nvidia's 260.19.36 driver.

```
[junit] CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE
[junit] org.jocl.CLException: CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE
```

Comment: what driver are you using? What do you mean when you say crashing? Out of resources exception or segfaults?

Answer (score 0):

When approaching a memory leak (regardless of what frameworks are used in your projects)  it is a good idea to look at a few things.

- Are you getting a OutOfMemoryException? If you are, perhaps you do not have a -Xmin JMV variable set telling the JVM how much memory to start with. If you start with too little and the heap grows too fast, you can actually crash the JVM. So you can try to play with that.
- Do you know how much memory you are consuming? You can have your application dump the current memory usage or record the number of times your gc is running. If your gc runs really high, either you need to tune the gc, or perhaps you have a leak.
- Find an application profiler (in our case, we are a heavy IBM shop, so we use their profilers, but I'm sure there are free ones out there). This can help you navigate the heap during regular application usage if you suspect a leak. It will show you exactly how much heap you are using and what object are tending to "hand around" and not get cleaned up.

I know these are kind of generic. But they are the checklist we go through first when we suspect a memory leak.

Comment: I feel like since I am working with GPUs, I don't know how to apply those solid techniques. To be honest, I wish I could just use Valgrind on the GPU, but that capability isn't there yet I believe...

Comment: are you sure you are releasing all the CL objects properly? You could take a look at http://jocl.jogamp.org, it offers a high level api additionally to the low level api which simplifies usage a lot and reduces the risk for leaks.

Comment: I feel confident that I am releasing all my CL objects properly, but there must be something wrong at some point in the code.

Comment: if you are confident that you are releasing everything properly the only factor what is left is a bug in the CL implementation or a bug in jocl.org. We are testing on all CL implementations and never run into this (but we use jocl.jogamp.org).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL code (the kernel code) should not bring you any Memory Leak due to the missing concept of dynamic memory. The effect can only come from JOCL, Java or the underlying vendor libraries for the devices used. The vendor libraries are unlikely the cause, but a new version of drivers and libraries were a guess.

Some class allocates memory on the OpenCL device without freeing it. Are you sure, that you also free the OpenCL memory in cases of thrown exceptions?